# Difference in PCR Measurements for a Same VM Image on DIfferent Platforms

Tags: tpm

I have a VM Image and I am deploying it across two different environments.
Firstly I am deploying this VM Image onto QEMU Emulator on my Host Machine and then secondly at the same time, I am importing this VM Image to GCP and spinning up a VM Instance.

Even when it is the same VM Image, but when I am orchestrating the instance on GCP and QEMU, I am getting different PCR Measurements.

I am curious as to why is this the case ? Even for a Exact same VM Image; why I am getting completely different PCR Measurements ?

PCR Values I am getting from the QEMU Emulator:

```
root@ubuntu:~# sudo tpm2_pcrread sha1: 0 : 0x3A3F780F11A4B49969FCAA80CD6E3957C33B2275 1 : 0x20E322E8173566759FA9B8410C0CD0B8366E9D4E 2 : 0xE763D0DDA75BAF5D8E1B7176D8D70FA82BD87C0D 3 : 0x3A3F780F11A4B49969FCAA80CD6E3957C33B2275 4 : 0x539618EF5AB9307A836FB919AC181F19586D46A9 5 : 0x7213A89EBFA0CBAD2AC8EF3371AF1DF6E77F9B40 6 : 0x3A3F780F11A4B49969FCAA80CD6E3957C33B2275 7 : 0x3A3F780F11A4B49969FCAA80CD6E3957C33B2275 8 : 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 9 : 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 10: 0x0668B664F9F54483759D6A78B113DE952DAA9715 11: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 12: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 13: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 14: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 15: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 16: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 17: 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 18: 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 19: 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 20: 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 21: 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 22: 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 23: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 sha256: 0 : 0xD27CC12614B5F4FF85ED109495E320FB1E5495EB28D507E952D51091E7AE2A72 1 : 0x6576ACBA755FFF7080823DA3873415D2F00F0AB4983FBB42D9B331690D342299 2 : 0x6689E3F4786639475141BD85F6A9F2CF1AF984BF876DA851C2CEC47752D9985B 3 : 0xD27CC12614B5F4FF85ED109495E320FB1E5495EB28D507E952D51091E7AE2A72 4 : 0xAAE2B679645D159CD46CB88EC77645A3AFB30CE15090DC9C2F982A4FB94DA6F0 5 : 0x12DBC5BB8B9B1B070A12F00FBEFDC9DF29C46B2400699344A5D96B1AD7DD5248 6 : 0xD27CC12614B5F4FF85ED109495E320FB1E5495EB28D507E952D51091E7AE2A72 7 : 0xD27CC12614B5F4FF85ED109495E320FB1E5495EB28D507E952D51091E7AE2A72 8 : 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 9 : 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 10: 0xF510C811C619FEE004C2F4BA42720DAFD042AE2C6CA4B7D534AD938AC4D5D367 11: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 12: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 13: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 14: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 15: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 16: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 17: 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 18: 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 19: 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 20: 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 21: 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 22: 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 23: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 sha384: 0 : 0xDB5CF089069BE9E0535F436B37786CAF1C730A01C33C24618712B7726B535E646A85D35267204F8BC6C87B04D314275A 1 : 0x06ED134A05367C3E9F6CAB5391C0002B40E483611615E9A2C0B3A3081FC2927CC318583EDAF13C46A80D6EE980B84742 2 : 0x17358451E0EE8287A914DF85819D38084F332686957E845E79B8030F0BB612C7DF3BA282FE0429DD6810FAB2741B7CEC 3 : 0xDB5CF089069BE9E0535F436B37786CAF1C730A01C33C24618712B7726B535E646A85D35267204F8BC6C87B04D314275A 4 : 0x4A9F1F2678CD71E788DC13D754320388EF879FDBAC5097E85C3DFE3310C08B6566C2D01D4140579137503E320F98D00A 5 : 0xAB3DAF8597D651A0EEAADC16FC6FC3A843BFFAE41651A67C3D07288295122C14E0382F193A5F09987C969C2A43AB21C0 6 : 0xDB5CF089069BE9E0535F436B37786CAF1C730A01C33C24618712B7726B535E646A85D35267204F8BC6C87B04D314275A 7 : 0xDB5CF089069BE9E0535F436B37786CAF1C730A01C33C24618712B7726B535E646A85D35267204F8BC6C87B04D314275A 8 : 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 9 : 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 10: 0x727023185757ADD17E6D481FE2773C34E35F1EFC3A9FE0132F974432F895A33642EF2A91E5E5FB32F3708AF87236D2DD 11: 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 12: 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 13: 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 14: 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 15: 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 16: 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 17: 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 18: 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 19: 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 20: 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 21: 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 22: 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 23: 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 sha512: 0 : 0x1BE3D27E52C61150FE5D385649A90FDA30FD6B1CB6BF4624CF9C77E1AF50CCC1F765A43E3C696064A354847723518B89F5501C82EA059723B703FCB1FA1EB175 1 : 0x09E9E17E615D24AEBDB0E8A8CA816D9E6C3FC7BA1AE301772A7D59525926F3C05E0B9FBA17D78E9A72EBC751235D886A75C033B214D535235BEEFF9519A148B7 2 : 0x55C578008E9F644DE7EF90F1669073173C06F0DDAF69C1D4C4C9DE269EE86E96B2E311129090D4819CB2F8C3E76801A3656E2F57144D953AA0ABFF078BF9E805 3 : 0x1BE3D27E52C61150FE5D385649A90FDA30FD6B1CB6BF4624CF9C77E1AF50CCC1F765A43E3C696064A354847723518B89F5501C82EA059723B703FCB1FA1EB175 4 : 0x775519CD28BA07045A639273032AEEC747F9AAE846A513194E3674730C30A41A6330C0B9623E5C144D958A211F2D6B2B445B5B28BD3112DCB7E3F9624EDC9FA2 5 : 0x227F7CEB659CD39B1DC02A383531ECFDB40CB1D3F4156B553F51E43242C45936F776F4624EF2A99FC41279622FD8EFC7B3519BD76354A169EEBE0A2DBC7F0669 6 : 0x1BE3D27E52C61150FE5D385649A90FDA30FD6B1CB6BF4624CF9C77E1AF50CCC1F765A43E3C696064A354847723518B89F5501C82EA059723B703FCB1FA1EB175 7 : 0x1BE3D27E52C61150FE5D385649A90FDA30FD6B1CB6BF4624CF9C77E1AF50CCC1F765A43E3C696064A354847723518B89F5501C82EA059723B703FCB1FA1EB175 8 : 0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 9 : 0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 10: 0x4EDDD92F675A2F7782C9666F5D913EB337AE9229F1544E6906AAD0E6EECAC189B818BCDA75A740CA998A3C1DAEBD6A47273EAD307FBCC56A6019D228D972FDEA 11: 0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 12: 0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 13: 0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 14: 0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 15: 0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 16: 0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 17: 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 18: 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 19: 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 20: 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 21: 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 22: 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 23: 0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

PCR Values from GCP:

```
root@ubuntu:~# sudo tpm2_pcrread sha1: 0 : 0x2AAB58E23EA5120D70A3EBCE56BD0E6D5E3035B7 1 : 0x6EBDF9810C49DB289E4353F092459872BADD1D56 2 : 0xB2A83B0EBF2F8374299A5B2BDFC31EA955AD7236 3 : 0xB2A83B0EBF2F8374299A5B2BDFC31EA955AD7236 4 : 0x4612460400DAC8FAE53618C4AB494C6A9FF3AF3C 5 : 0x0DA40D4B48CF052449939BC9797C3FA2443C47DB 6 : 0xB2A83B0EBF2F8374299A5B2BDFC31EA955AD7236 7 : 0x9E093142D444BE07DC2A8D621186AF914FA65E63 8 : 0x349CD2BDB6412DAB492B5802D0A6F6AD580EFAE3 9 : 0xA0E6E336E23555ECD51CA1AC692F2DBB9AD9F738 10: 0x93924BBA0281DF12DD6E18A2591E8F9BDE1ADEE2 11: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 12: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 13: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 14: 0xA482A15E112717D6A915B989A0EA6140A507E3E6 15: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 16: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 17: 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 18: 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 19: 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 20: 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 21: 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 22: 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 23: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 sha256: 0 : 0xA0B5FF3383A1116BD7DC6DF177C0C2D433B9EE1813EA958FA5D166A202CB2A85 1 : 0xD5D9E3EC5899173861AEF2EDADA9F73E2370507F66FDA8C3962E730B5A7BB282 2 : 0x3D458CFE55CC03EA1F443F1562BEEC8DF51C75E14A9FCF9A7234A13F198E7969 3 : 0x3D458CFE55CC03EA1F443F1562BEEC8DF51C75E14A9FCF9A7234A13F198E7969 4 : 0x1F0105624AB37B9AF59DA6618A406860E33EF6F42A38DDAF6ABFAB8F23802755 5 : 0x0089D0996F64E5E9520E1B52D6D0A46264F86706F25228AC72B40D4D9717C75C 6 : 0x3D458CFE55CC03EA1F443F1562BEEC8DF51C75E14A9FCF9A7234A13F198E7969 7 : 0xF833DADFBDD00F779F4AB3BD589F4828700AA6CB81AC0D38424600D64A928DA1 8 : 0xCE8A8899AD90AB3AAA2B1C5364561C098C0C29E12942B9E6096B12E1F825038A 9 : 0xD49585D5160D71C73C715180E4D03AA0EB2E8DDD3E4FFFF77FEAB4B7A51EA472 10: 0x45A69FC7F24E8F7A73DB92590612C80CC88D4946AB02A9E1CC2B05A43181612A 11: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 12: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 13: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 14: 0x306F9D8B94F17D93DC6E7CF8F5C79D652EB4C6C4D13DE2DDDC24AF416E13ECAF 15: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 16: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 17: 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 18: 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 19: 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 20: 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 21: 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 22: 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 23: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 sha384: 0 : 0x46384721A6CBBB845096CCF31553E49E0EE2F5F7A488E0D98CA676AAAB6EBBB30888A5424D90D9ECCBF59F461DB8DA35 1 : 0x1173B34D7D9C8DC62DF51DDCDB98B8D86FC0ECFC898F78D94EC36A2D0E30ADC98C38FBD228B63C627CCA1AE179CCA996 2 : 0x518923B0F955D08DA077C96AABA522B9DECEDE61C599CEA6C41889CFBEA4AE4D50529D96FE4D1AFDAFB65E7F95BF23C4 3 : 0x518923B0F955D08DA077C96AABA522B9DECEDE61C599CEA6C41889CFBEA4AE4D50529D96FE4D1AFDAFB65E7F95BF23C4 4 : 0x966EA29F6744FA88E5842AE51EF6E32A9519D4BAD8A3F53FCF25C2CAB940B57CF7F85AD08769889A0EA0D0442DFD45CE 5 : 0x2BE4D79619916C4ACA91E93E08ED58940D000D05B6266F6621675000D46333EA8B7E357CB4590C2B0208F15DCED18BBC 6 : 0x518923B0F955D08DA077C96AABA522B9DECEDE61C599CEA6C41889CFBEA4AE4D50529D96FE4D1AFDAFB65E7F95BF23C4 7 : 0xB68D98B421216BC81AFBEE743837821D92E3B790FF8B61179955A3C7F0D8220E5B6D193340B61F1F3346BDAA6443CD49 8 : 0xA6C75D9BCDB19DA53E562F4C8BB9557E15A73B5553C283225676383DCE468539E7FC46D02D869EF9F8F46516726A85EE 9 : 0x54211E902D079C02FB4D4A00CBA2A08916D3E4D96EEFDCF0F29310B45CC9EEACEF50604FEA74C254314190C2895455B6 10: 0x7608D7A5AF573005A1E17537547548E6B928FC728D3FB13E0F769077F24CA0F7649D5304662363E8A176FE027ED176DE 11: 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 12: 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 13: 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 14: 0x937437D07298010015F4598395C9F8DC202EF36E0BE3897BBA89874BF612B5DA092BEADFE37F79714A60193819E384AD 15: 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 16: 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 17: 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 18: 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 19: 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 20: 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 21: 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 22: 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 23: 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: Which registers are different? 0-3 are measuring firmware and system related values and i would expect different values for different firmwares (QEMU, GCP).

Comment: All registers are different, not even one register is similar on both QEMU and GCP

Comment: Can you post your pcr values, and the tool that you are using for reading them?

Comment: I am using TPM 2 tools for reading the PCR Values

Comment: @MiSimon Updating the PCR Values in the question itself

Comment: You can use the tpm2_eventlog utility (from the TPM2 tools) to view the tpm2 eventlog, this should show you what values got measured and where the differences are.

Comment: I used the same but it only shows the result for PCR_0 Index and after that index it gave me the error message of Index out of Bounds

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253108/discussion-between-deepanshu-arora-and-misimon).

Answer (score 0):

Each PCR register measures a special set of values.

- 0-7 are used to measure firmware values ([more infos)](https://trustedcomputinggroup.org/wp-content/uploads/TCG_PCClient_PFP_r1p05_v23_pub.pdf)
- 8-15 are used to measure os values (more infos [linux](https://uapi-group.org/specifications/specs/linux_tpm_pcr_registry/), [windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/information-protection/bitlocker/bitlocker-group-policy-settings#about-the-platform-configuration-register-pcr))
- 16 can be used for testing and debugging

The registers 0-7 can vary even if the same disk image is used and the hardware is identical, they depend on the firmware, firmware version, boot order, boot config, ...

The registers 8, 9, 10 and 14 are different because you booted in different modes (bios and uefi).

If a register has all bits set or cleared (except register 0) it is in its initial state.

Comment: Even booting with the Same Boot Modes on both the Ends(UEFI) still results in different PCRS for registers 8,9,10 and 14

Comment: Can you please post both boot orders?

Comment: Why are the Values for PCR 8-15 being set as 000XFFF meaning why are they not being extended even though in the VM Image, all the components are included ?

Comment: Maybe neither grub nor shim are used (efistub) and your kernel does not measure anything (may be coupled to ima being enabled or not, but that would be a question for [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/kernel)).

Comment: Also, according to you, would it be possible/or is there a way through which measurements of a VM Image can directly be calculated instead of spinning up the VM and then calculating the PCR measurements inside of the VM ?

Comment: Maybe for some registers, if you know exactly what they are being used for. But i would not rely on that. Every update of firmware and/or software components can change them.

Comment: still any tool that you are aware of that helps in calculating those measurements based off the VM Image ?

Comment: I am not aware on any tools that to do the calculation.